# Angular js code got terminated after error using

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to plot some graphics in website. i have observed that code got terminated after error.

Comment: Could you please update the error and code into the question?

Comment: Show the related code and error! by single line of explanation it won't help too much! Or it can be done by simple `try {} catch(e){console.log(e)}` block?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what throws the error, but you have two options for this.

1. Just wrap the code block in a basic try/catch to catch fatal errors (in the iteration).
2. Implement an `$exceptionHandler` service to catch/handle any application-level errors to keep your application running when errors occur.

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$exceptionHandler for more information.

The second option is the most preferred, because this handles any exception, which means that your application will "never" terminate due to an error and you can add your own custom handler for what to do to when your application happens to throw an exception (like send it to a monitoring service or something like that).

Comment: How to add exception handler in code part